# Android Mobile Push App example from Amazon Web Services

Tags: java, android, amazon-web-services

Have anyone tried to add AndroidMobilePushApp (is provided by AWS) into Eclipse IDE, follow by this tutorial (http://docs.aws.amazon.com/sns/latest/dg/mobile-push-gcm.html) and able to get registrationID for the Amazon Mobile Push app?

I am able to add AndroidMobilePushApp into Eclipse along with 2 extraneous library .jar (android.jar, google-play-service) without any error, created Google API project on Google APIs Console website and copied that project_number into **[res/values/strings.xml]** according step 3 from the tutorial above. However, when I deploy the application into an Android device (Version 2.3.6 and API level 10), the app does show up,but it doesn't run when I click on...with error says " The application Amazon Mobile Push ( process com.amazonaws.androidtest) has stopped unexpectedly. Please try again! " so It won't able to give me back registration ID as step 4 from the tutorial above.

Any idea why?

Thanks,
Don

Comment: Do you have the stacktrace. Post you LogCat. See you LogCat. I will hep identify the reason.

Comment: Screenshot of LogCat is in this link http://d.pr/i/RDxl .Let me know if you need to filter anything. Thanks!

Comment: Please don't screenshot logcat. For one thing, it has run off the screen. For another, it can't be searched or reformatted.

Answer (score 2):

I had trouble w/ that sample code also. I finally got AndroidMobilePush to work but not SNSMobilePush in the same tutorial.

Hard to tell what you have done or left out, but I can give you some ideas of where to look:

1. Check if you have changed package names any place.
2. I had to declare the PLAY_SERVICES_RESOLUTION_REQUEST = 9000; constant needed in checkPlayServices()
3. Make sure you have not blocked execution of checkPlayServices and register()

I would set a Log filter to make sure you are at least getting that far. Then, of course, set another to capture the registrationID so you can save it to log.txt. Copy that and supply it to the SNS Console in AWS when you Add Endpoints.

Answer (score 0):

Read carefully Step 3, point 4 and associated image.

If you remove `android.jar` from the export list, your app will run fine